# Distinction between ScheduledExecutorService and rolling your own Runnable with Thread.sleep()

Tags: java, multithreading, scheduled-tasks, scheduledexecutorservice

What are the benefits of using [`ScheduledExecutorService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html)'s [`scheduleAtFixedRate()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html#scheduleAtFixedRate-java.lang.Runnable-long-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-) to run a piece of code on a regular basis instead of creating a new [`Runnable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html) that has a forever loop coupled with a [`Thread.sleep()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep-long-) that causes the thread to sleep for the desired period?

Is there a performance gain with one of the methods?

Answer (score 9):

The biggest benefit of using `ScheduledExecutorService` is that you don't need to write the code, and that it is well tested. It does also have support for cancelling tasks out of the box, and you can schedule more than one task.

Another benefit is that other developers know what the `ScheduledExecutorService` does, they can read the javadoc, and they can ask questions about it on puplic forums, and get help, while it's harder to get help for custom code.

The javadoc for [ScheduledExecutorService](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) does also have a good example of how to create a tasks that executes every 10 seconds for an hour, and then gets cancelled.

Comment: Note @dlev's caveat: Tasks are not guaranteed to run at exact intervals due to excessive task duration and/or thread starvation

Comment: You might also hope that a library class would handle the complexities of what is supposed to happen if the clock time changes. Whether it actually does is another matter ;-)

Comment: True, but we will probably have to live with that flaw for many years to come :(