# Java. Difference between Thread.sleep() and ScheduledExecutorService methods

Tags: java, thread-sleep, scheduledexecutorservice

I'm trying to make a clock desktop app and was using

```
Thread.sleep(1000);
```

inside a while(true) loop.  When I was wondering how this works and might affect CPU performance, I found that ScheduledExecutorService is more preferable and claimed by some StackOverflowers to be more accurate.

**What's the difference between them?**

(also saw another option using swing timers, but more curious about "advanced" stuff)

EDIT: To be more specific:

From: [Java 7 doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html)

> The scheduleAtFixedRate and scheduleWithFixedDelay methods create and execute tasks that run periodically until cancelled.

Is there any difference between Thread.sleep() and these 2 methods? (threads usage, CPU consumption, precision, when is better to use one or another, etc)

Comment: That's a bit like asking what the difference between you taking a nap and the organizational structure of a bunch of people working on an assembly line is. You need to narrow this down to something specific and comparable.

Comment: Also, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6183749/distinction-between-scheduledexecutorservice-and-rolling-your-own-runnable-with